# Delphi no provisioning profile found for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, firemonkey

In order to meet AppStore's min requirement of iOS SDK 11.3
on the Mac I had to update to XCode 9.4.1 and macOS Mojave, but now I can't make Delphi 10.3.2 iOS provisioning to work. it worked before that.

With XCode I built, deployed and run a "Hello World" app on the iphone, so I figure certificates and provisioning are correct.

On Delphi I set Build configuration=Debug,  Target=iOS Device 64 - iOS SDK 11.4

When I click Project > Options > Provisioning there is an error:
"No provisioning profile found for the selected
build configuration and the selected device "iphoneX"

Using PAServer in verbose mode, I can see that
Delphi runs 1 command on PAServer to detect provisioning failure

"/usr/bin/security" find-identity -v

Running this command on a separate Terminal i got:

```
1) 79...B99A "Developer ID Application: OMARR (V7..29)"
2) 0AC...9E3 "Developer ID Installer: OMARR (V7..29)"
3) 342...DB4 "iPhone Distribution: OMARR (V7..29)”
4) 21...8D4C "iPhone Developer: OmarR (W92..BB)"
```

And Delphi goes “No provisioning profile found..”
May be the problem has to do with the certificate names.
I used Xcode automatic certificate creation

I tried to find some option for Provisioning on Delphi
but it seems there is only the "Auto" mode.

I'm stuck ...

Comment: Check the value you have for CFBundleIdentifier in the Project Options, Version Info. It needs to match the one used when you created the App Id that is tied to the provisioning profile. Also ensure that the provisioning profile(s) are actually on the Mac - in Xcode, click the Xcode menu, select Preferences, and go to the Accounts tab. Select the desired account, and click "Download Manual Profiles"

Comment: When I click XCode Preferences Accounts App ID "Manage Certificates", developer certificate is listed as "Untitled". May be this causes the problem ?

Comment: Using XCode iOS Wildcard app ID (*) for provisioning. CFBundleIdentifier=$(ModuleName)

Comment: I didn't know you could run Xcode 9.x on Mojave. It was my understanding that it required Xcode 10.

Also, in the past when I had difficulties with Delphi finding iOS provisioning, it started working after I restarted the PAServer, and after I deployed a simple app from Xcode (which I see you tried).

Answer (score 0):

Check that all the entries that it lists are valid. I was getting four as well but the first two had `(CSSMERR_TP_CERT_REVOKED)` written at the end of each line but nevertheless at the end it displayed `4 valid identities found`.

The Keychain Access app doesn't show the revoked certificates with any marker to show that they are invalid so it was not obvious. However after I found and deleted the two revoked certificates, I noticed that paserver issued `"/usr/bin/security" find-certificate -p -a -c ....` commands for the two remaining good certificates. It did not do this before so I can only assume it had stopped due to the revoked status of the first two certificates. It also did not do this again but that is perhaps because those certificates had already been checked.

However in my case I guess it still wasn't happy with the result of those commands because Delphi still displays the ambiguous "No provisioning profile found for the selected build configuration" message so I'm still stuck as well. It seems to me that Embarcadero could display a more detailed message about what actually goes wrong or what is missing rather than just the one message that could be the result of 100 different problems.

Edit: after creating a new provisioning profile using an explicit app ID, manually downloading it (because the download in Xcode failed to work), rebooting the mac several times, suddenly it progressed on to another error message so I guess that is success.

Comment: I revoked and recreated developer certificate, provisioning profile. Installed by hand (not by XCode). In keys application there is only the "iphone Developer" certificate. XCode sees it and is able to install and run apps in the phone. But Delphi cannot ...

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Delphi 10.3 Rio solved the problem